# How to seperate this string using by Reg Exp

Tags: c++, regex, string

For this string `[268, 950][268, 954][269, 955][272, 955][270, 955][268, 953]`

I want to get the numbers in `[ , ]` pair by pair.

I use c++ regex_search to parse this string.

This is my testing code:

```
ifstream  file("output.txt");

char regex_base[] = "[\\[0-9, 0-9\\]]{10}";
char regex_num[] = "[0-9]{3}";

regex reg_base(regex_base, regex_constants::icase);
regex reg_num(regex_base, regex_constants::icase);

if (file.is_open())
{
    string s;
    while (!file.eof()){
        getline(file, s);
        smatch m;
        while (regex_search(s, m, reg_num)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
                cout << m[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

But in the `while` of `regex_search()`, the variable `m` only get the[268, 950] and it make a infinity loop.

What's wrong in my regular expression or my code?

Comment: If I were you I will write a basic algorithm to do that.

Comment: It's an infinite loop because you're calling it on the same string in an infinite loop. Additionally, `while (!file.eof())` is wrong.

Comment: What is the best way to get the number in string, I am so confused.

Comment: your pattern appears a bit off. Try `"\\[[0-9]+, [0-9]+\\]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the capturing groups since you seem not to be using them anyway, and added some code to just show how to obtain the matches from your input string:

```
char regex_base[] = "\\[[0-9]+, [0-9]+\\]";
...
s = "[268, 950][268, 954][269, 955][272, 955][270, 955][268, 953]"; // FOR TEST
smatch m;
while (regex_search(s, m, reg_num)) 
{
    for (auto x:m) std::cout << x << "\r\n";
    s = m.suffix().str();
}
```

Output:

[image]

If you need the values, you can use a different regex:

```
char regex_base[] = "\\[([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)\\]";
...
s = "[268, 950][268, 954][269, 955][272, 955][270, 955][268, 953]";
smatch m;
while (regex_search(s, m, reg_num)) 
{
    std::cout << m[1] << ", " << m[2] << std::endl;
    s = m.suffix().str();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I miss "s = m.suffix().str();" and write wrong reg exp.